# Use chunkhash only for some output files in webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am building an application that is being loaded as a plugin in other applications. Think grammarly or intercom.
So, I will have a javascript file (the loader) that customers need to reference in their application.
This file in turn adds an iFrame and loads my index.html which references my main bundle.

Now, I want to have the loader to not have a chunkhash in its filename but the bundle should have the chunkhash.

Possible? If so, how?

My webpack config (ejected from `create-react-app-typescript`):

```
entry: {
    app: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
    loader: "./src/integration/loader.ts"
},
output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
        path
            .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
            .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
},
```

Comment: Can you add a little more information about your project structure? That would be really helpful.

Comment: @AravindanVe Not sure what exactly you need to know. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use a function for `filename`.

```
...
output: {
    ...
    filename: (chunkData) => {
        return chunkData.chunk.name === 'loader'
            ? '[name].js'
            : '[name].[chunkhash:8].js';
    },
}
```

See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename

Comment: That wouldn't help as this would also remove the hash from the build result of the app entry point.

Comment: If your loader is simply a couple of lines that loads an iframe, do you really need to use webpack? You can write the loader in plain es5 right? Which just loads your index.html that references the main bundle with the correct chunk hash

Comment: The loader is more. It also has integration with different edit fields and wysiwyg editors, so it does warrent a webpack build. The resulting bundle is about 1/3 of the size of the bundle of the logic that is loaded in the iFrame

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have edited my answer, does this work for you?

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I am looking for. However, I am currently at webpack 3.x. Will need to update to webpack 4.x first